# Update Deployment Target iOS - older App versions still available

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to raise the deployment target of my iOS App from iOS 7 to iOS 8.

I searched a lot and found many threads saying that after the App-Update iOS 7 Users would not be able to download the current updated version.

This is okay, but can iOS 7 Users still downloaded an outdated Version of my app which is compatible with iOS 7 deployment targets?

This behaviour we've in android - there we can publish multiple versions of a single app.

Comment: If they've already downloaded your app before they will be able to download the last version that supports their os, but any new users won't be able to get your app without updating to iOS 8

Answer (score 3):

In iTunesConnect you can manage your settings concerning that issue under:
**MyApps** >> **[Your App]** >> **Pricing and Availability**

It there says that if users that own a device that is incompatible to your latest update will be able to download the last working version of it. (You can uncheck versions you do not want to be available if they contain critical bugs for instance.)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Ok great, but then the comment from @dan to my question (see above) is not the truth?

Comment: Well I think so because Apple does not state users that have downloaded your app previously but users in general. I'm not 100% positive though.